# OSGi tests no longer working after upgrading from Groovy 2.5 to Groovy 3.0

Tags: groovy, osgi, maven-3, pax-exam

I have a pax-exam test that looks like this:

```java
@RunWith(PaxExam.class)
public class XmlPathOSGiITest {

    @Configuration
    public static Option[] configure() {
        return new Option[]
                {
                        /* System Properties */
                        systemProperty(EXAM_FAIL_ON_UNRESOLVED_KEY).value("true"),
                        systemProperty("org.ops4j.pax.logging.DefaultServiceLog.level").value("INFO"),

                        /* Hamcrest & JUnit bundles */
                        restAssuredJunitBundles(),

                        /* Transitive dependencies needed in the Pax Exam container.
                        Some of these need to be wrapped because they are not available as OSGi bundles */
                        mavenBundle().groupId("org.apache.aries.spifly").artifactId("org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle").version("1.2.1"),
                        mavenBundle().groupId("org.hamcrest").artifactId("hamcrest").versionAsInProject(),
                        mavenBundle().groupId("org.apache.commons").artifactId("commons-lang3").versionAsInProject(),
                        mavenBundle().groupId("org.codehaus.groovy").artifactId("groovy-json").versionAsInProject().noStart(),
                        mavenBundle().groupId("org.codehaus.groovy").artifactId("groovy-xml").versionAsInProject().noStart(),
                        mavenBundle().groupId("org.codehaus.groovy").artifactId("groovy").versionAsInProject(),

                        wrappedBundle(mavenBundle().groupId("org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup").artifactId("tagsoup").versionAsInProject()),
                        wrappedBundle(mavenBundle("jakarta.xml.bind", "jakarta.xml.bind-api").versionAsInProject()),
                        wrappedBundle(mavenBundle("javax.activation", "activation").version("1.1.1")),
                        wrappedBundle(mavenBundle("org.apache.httpcomponents", "httpclient").versionAsInProject()),
                        wrappedBundle(mavenBundle("org.apache.httpcomponents", "httpmime").versionAsInProject()),
                        wrappedBundle(mavenBundle("org.apache.httpcomponents", "httpcore").versionAsInProject()),

                        /* Rest Assured dependencies needed in the Pax Exam container to be able to execute the tests below */
                        mavenBundle("io.rest-assured", "json-path").versionAsInProject(),
                        mavenBundle("io.rest-assured", "xml-path").versionAsInProject(),
                        mavenBundle("io.rest-assured", "rest-assured").versionAsInProject(),
                        mavenBundle("io.rest-assured", "rest-assured-common").versionAsInProject()
                };
    }

    @Test
    public void getUUIDParsesAStringResultToUUID() {
        final String UUID_XML = "<some>\n" +
                "  <thing id=\"1\">db24eeeb-7fe5-41d3-8f06-986b793ecc91</thing>\n" +
                "  <thing id=\"2\">d69ded28-d75c-460f-9cbe-1412c60ed4cc</thing>\n" +
                "</some>";

        final UUID uuid = from(UUID_XML).getUUID("some.thing[0]");

        assertThat(uuid, Matchers.equalTo(UUID.fromString("db24eeeb-7fe5-41d3-8f06-986b793ecc91")));
    }
}
```

This used to work fine with Groovy 2.5 but after upgrading to Groovy 3.0 I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter not found by groovy-xml [20]

    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1597)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$300(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1982)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.getClassByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1375)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.searchImports(BundleWiringImpl.java:1618)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1548)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$300(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1982)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at io.restassured.internal.common.assertion.AssertParameter.notNull(AssertParameter.groovy:25)
    at io.restassured.path.xml.XmlPath.get(XmlPath.java:316)
    at io.restassured.path.xml.XmlPath.getUUID(XmlPath.java:584)
    at io.restassured.test.osgi.XmlPathOSGiITest.getUUIDParsesAStringResultToUUID(XmlPathOSGiITest.java:84)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.ContainerTestRunner.runLeafWithRetry(ContainerTestRunner.java:97)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.ContainerTestRunner.runChildWithRetry(ContainerTestRunner.java:84)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.ContainerTestRunner.runChild(ContainerTestRunner.java:75)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.ContainerTestRunner.runChild(ContainerTestRunner.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.invokeViaJUnit(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:124)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.findAndInvoke(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:97)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.call(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:73)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.framework.RemoteFrameworkImpl.invokeMethodOnService(RemoteFrameworkImpl.java:435)
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.framework.RemoteFrameworkImpl.invokeMethodOnService(RemoteFrameworkImpl.java:408)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I've checked `mvn dependency:tree` to make sure that I have no remnants of Groovy 2.5.x still in the classpath.

What could be the cause of this and how do I fix it? Note that you can find the project on github [here](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/tree/master/examples/rest-assured-itest-java-osgi).

Comment: From the stacktrace it looks like at this point:
io.restassured.internal.common.assertion.AssertParameter.notNull(AssertParameter.groovy:25)
The class ScriptBytecodeAdapter would be loaded but it does not have any such call. Is that an internal error of groovy?

Comment: ScriptBytecodeAdapter is one if the internal classes of the Groovy runtime, used as interfacing between the Groovy runtime and the generated bytecode. All standard non-direct method calls are made this way. The "groovy" artifact contains this class. As of why it is not loaded, I can't tell. Maybe prepare a minimal project and ask on the Apache Groovy users list

Comment: Is this the full stack trace? Sometimes a class cannot be loaded because it uses a dependency that is missing at runtime.

Comment: Yes this is the full stacktrace.

Comment: ClassNotFoundException in OSGi can be due to wrong metadata (the class is on the classpath, but a specific bundle can not find it because of the module isolation). 
I think I have reproduced a quite similar issue in a simple project (no rest-assured, no PaxExam test, using Bndtools): https://github.com/jmini/bnd-experiments/tree/master/groovy-v3-xml-test 
The same test with groovy 2.5.9 is ok: https://github.com/jmini/bnd-experiments/tree/master/groovy-v2-xml-test

Comment: I have opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9402

Comment: @Johan have you a way to test with `3.0.2-SNAPSHOT` to ensure that the fix of GROOVY-9402  is working for you?

Comment: @Jmini I've tried it with 3.0.2-SNAPSHOT now and it works!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discussion here raised issue [GROOVY-9402](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9402) which is fixed with version `3.0.2` of Groovy.

**Summary:**

The OSGi Metadata are wrong with Groovy `3.0.0` and `3.0.1`.

In the early development phase of Groovy `3.0`, the team wanted to get rid of the split packages between the different modules (JPMS module system) and updated the OSGi Metadata accordingly.

Later they decided to add some deprecated classes at the old package location to indicate that the classes were moved (this means that Groovy `3.0` has split packages issues and the JPMS support will be added with `4.0`). During this operation the OSGi Metadata were not fixed. This is solved with Groovy `3.0.2`

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be caused by the groovy internal class loading. Likely groovy uses the class loader of the user bundle to load its own class ScriptBytecodeAdapter. It should use its own class loader for this. Btw. The easiest way to get such class loaders is to get the class loader of a known class.

In OSGi the class loader of a class is always the class loader of the bundle the class resides in.

Comment: In my example https://github.com/jmini/bnd-experiments/tree/master/groovy-v3-xml-test the ScriptBytecodeAdapter class is not involved: `NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/xml/XmlParser`. Could this be due to broken metadata? I have opened this issue to investigate: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9402

Comment: I guess you refer to that groovy should export an additional package. I think this is not the case here. It would only help if the user package would actually refer to the package. If the class that is not found is internal then usually the wrong classloader is used. Still it makes sense to report the error.